# how to use Module name with $scope?

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller

Is it possible to use Module name and `$scope` variable?

For example my module name is `app`

I want to use in controller like this

```
$scope.app.variableName = 'hello';
```

Comment: controllers are assigned to apps, not other way around. The scope is also only for each controller. You can't attach it to the module

Comment: it cannot be done in $scope as you have described..although it looks like you want to share data between controllers..you can use angular providers https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers which is better way..other way having your variable in $rootscope.